# Is there any flutter analysis available regarding Falcon's grid fins?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, grid-fins, analysis

I have never come across any papers which talks about flutter analysis of gridded fins in general, does it not under go flutter behavior or is it technically incorrect to talk about flutter for gridded fins?

Comment: I would guess the grid structure prevents it being much of an issue.
"Numerical studies of static aeroelastic effects on grid fin aerodynamic performances" from the Chinese Journal of Aeronautics might be helpful, or contain referernces to useful papers
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1000936117301206